# Updating Project References in VS 2019 Community edition

Tags: reference, dependencies

I have a WebApp and several APIs with each one having a project dependency on a class library project. I have changed the folder structure and moved around some of the class (.cs files) within the new folder structure of the class Library project. For example, I created a new Data folder and moved some of the .cs files from the Models folder to the Data folder.

However, whatever I do I cannot update the WebApp and API projects to take account of the new class library structure. I have tried Rebuilding the whole solution, unloading and reloading the class library project etc., but the WebApp and API projects are still bound to the old class library structure and do not recognise the existence of the new Data folder.

Any ideas on how to update the class library reference in teh WebApp and API projects to reflect the changes made?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am using a Mac

Comment: Please ignore this post as I found the problem. I had forgotten to change the Namespace when I copied the .cs files from the Models to Data folder.